# В ряду или в ряде

Tags: падежи

На сколько я понимаю, существует устоявшееся употребление падежей для слова ряд (в отличие от слов лес и бред) с предлогом "в" (первый и [второй](https://polit.ru/article/2016/05/23/itkin_photo/#:%7E:text=%D0%92%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B6%20%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B6%D0%B5%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F,%D0%B2%C2%BB%20%D0%B8%20%C2%AB%D0%BD%D0%B0%C2%BB.) предложный):

```
В ряде стран есть плановая экономика. 
В ряду стран, имеющих плановую экономику, есть богатые страны.
```

Есть ли действительно устоявшееся употребление? По какому принципу произошло разделение? И будет ли ошибкой писать:

```
Сейчас в ряду стран есть плановая экономика. 
В ряде стран, имеющих плановую экономику, есть богатые страны.
```

Comment: https://kak-pravilno.net/v-ryadu-ili-v-ryade-kak-pravilno/

Comment: У "в ряду" другой смысл: https://all_words.academic.ru/7387/в_ряду

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Словарь синонимов ASIS. В.Н. Тришин. 2013, а так же Словарь русских синонимов и сходных по смыслу выражений.- под. ред. Н. Абрамова, М.: Русские словари, 1999.
сочетанию «в ряду» приводят в соответствие синонимы: «среди»,  «в числе»,  «(про)между».

Словарь синонимов русского языка - онлайн https://sinonim.org/
к синонимам  сочетания «в ряде» причисляет: «в некоторых», «в нескольких», «в определенных», «в отдельных».

Согласно словарям, сочетания «в ряду» и «в ряде» имеют заметные смысловые отличия и потому синонимами не являются.

Их применение прямо зависит от контекста и нет никакого секрета в принципе выбора «в ряду» / «в ряде». Чтобы проверить фразу на правильность использования  сочетания (в ряду / в ряде), достаточно подставить на место этого сочетания соответствующий  ему синоним (среди / в некоторых).

Например, фразу: «В ряде стран есть плановая экономика» следует считать правильной, поскольку при подстановка соответствующего синонима получаем эквивалентное по смыслу: «В некоторых странах есть плановая экономика».
А вот замена сочетания «в некоторых» на (несоответствующее) «в ряду» не просто искажает смысл сообщения, но и дает неудобоваримый (ошибочный) вариант: «Сейчас в ряду стран есть плановая экономика».

Во втором примере, для фразы «В ряду стран, имеющих плановую экономику, есть богатые страны» эквивалентной будет - «Среди (/ в числе) стран, имеющих плановую экономику, есть богатые страны» .

Неестественность (ошибочность) фразы «В ряде стран, имеющих плановую экономику, есть богатые страны» становится совершенно очевидной, если сочетание «в ряде» заменить его синонимом: «В некоторых странах, имеющих плановую экономику, есть богатые страны».

Comment: Интересный ответ. А вы можете привести пример, с сочетанием "в ряду стран", может ли оно быть корректным?

Comment: Любопытно посмотреть на список всех слов, имеющих оба предложных падежа

Comment: Италии нет ни в ряду верных, ни в ряду неверных стран. [С. М. Алфеев. Ватикан (06.1945) // Журнал Московской Патриархии, № 07, 1945]

Comment: Россия первой столкнется с этой угрозой в ряду стран догоняющего развития. [Сергей Чернышев. Не пропустить волну // «Эксперт», 2014]

Comment: Ме́стный паде́ж, или локати́в - один из косвенных падежей, показывающий местонахождение предмета (в пространстве или во времени), обозначенного существительным. Отвечает на вопрос где? В русском языке местный падеж часто совпадает с предложным падежом (препозитивом) и поэтому в отдельный падеж не выделяется.https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B6  
Он занял место в ряду великих ученых ХХ века. / Он побывал в ряде высокоразвитых стран. / Он состоял в рядах самой популярной партии.

Comment: …неодушевлённые существительные мужского рода второго склонения характеризуются вариативными окончаниями -у/-ю или -е:

найти в лесу — расспросить о лесе
работать на дому — находиться в доме
мечтать о рае — находиться в раю
жить на Урале путешествовать по Уралу

Выбор этих окончаний зависит от многих условий
  см: https://russkiiyazyk.ru/chasti-rechi/sushhestvitelnoe/predlozhnyy-padezh.html  

снег, дым, сад, огород, цех, и т.д., список огромен...

Comment: @guaranteen Спасибо, ну раз список огромен, тогда можно поставить более строгое условие. Воспринимайте это как лингвозадачу на воображение. Привести пример хотя бы одного существительного, употребляющегося с одним и тем же предлогом как в первом предложном так и во втором предложном. Например слово "ряд" с предлогом "в". А есть ли еще такие слова?

Comment: Иногда он выныривал из дыма ― извивающийся, с закрытыми глазами, что-то шепчущий ― и снова пропадал в дыму. [Василий Аксенов. Круглые сутки нон-стоп // «Новый Мир», 1976]
- вместо «дым окутывает», говорим (и пишем) «в дыму».

Comment: Если дым из печи вылетает в трубу при температуре выше 80°R, то присутствие воды в дыме, уносящейся в виде пара, незаметно. [И. И. Свиязев. Письмо Е. А. и Н. А. Бестужевым (1851)]
- если речь идет о химическом составе дыма, то - «в дыме».